# Should I Delete a Down-Voted Feature Request?

Tags: discussion

On meta, votes on `feature-request`s are basically votes on whether people want the feature or not. So if a `feature-request` question is down-voted, should a user delete/close it? If is should be closed, for what reason?

Comment: It should stay as future reference I guess, for those with the same idea that have the courtesy to search before asking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd personally leave it, especially if it is [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).  That way others with the same request can see it as a reference.  Even if they only have a similar request, they can see what else they need to consider to improve their related request.  As long as the downvotes are more for disagreement rather than actually being incomprehensible I'd prefer to keep it.

Answer (score 2):

It should only be closed if it meets some criteria for closure.  If it's unclear what's being asked, a duplicate, etc. then it can be closed accordingly.  That the community doesn't like a suggestion wouldn't mean that any close reason necessarily applies.

As for deletion, outside of it being duplicate content that's been discussed to death, and that has nothing new its adding, no.  The post can remain as an artifact for future readers to understand why that particular feature wouldn't be useful.